# Compressing a text field in Sql Server 2k8 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have an application that stores a lot of text in a text field in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I'm adding about 5000 records a day, and that is going to grow.  The amount of data in the field can be between 4 KB and 100 KB.

I can change the field to be a blob field and store a byte stream in there (eg. zipped text), but I'm wondering if there is any compression option that I can use in SQL Server 2k8 (perhaps something designed for storing a lot of text?) that I could leverage using SQL Server out of the box?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

Regarding compatibility of [FILESTREAMS](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) :

- FILESTREAM feature is available with all versions of SQL Server 2008, including SQL Server Express.
- SQL Server Express database has a 4 GB limitation; however this limitation does not apply to the FILESTREAM data stored in a SQL Server Express database.

However [you need 'Developer Edition' or 'Enterprise Edition'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx) for Row / Page compression.

```
alter table pagevisit rebuild with (data_compression=page);
```

> Msg 7738, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Cannot enable compression for object
>   'PageVisit'. Only SQL Server
>   Enterprise Edition supports
>   compression.

Comment: Hi Simon_Weaver - so I'm using standard edition of SQL Server.  That rules out using the page compression command you've put above yeah?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2008 R2 has three compression options:

- [row compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280576.aspx)
- [page compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280464.aspx) (implies row compression)
- [unicode compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835.aspx)

All three options only apply to data (rows), so none could help with large documents (BLOBs). So your best option is to compress/decompress in the client (ZIP). I would not consider this option easily, it means you're trading off queriability of the data.

Comment: Hi - OK, so are either of those 3 options viable for me?  i.e. its not as simple as just turning on column compression for a given column in a table is it?

Comment: None of these 3 options will compress BLOB columns (`varbinary(max)`, `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)`), which would be the column ttpe you'd use to store a 'field' of 100KB.

Comment: So you're saying this is a no-go?  What do you think of demas's suggestion below?

Comment: @Ken Shaw: deploying FILESTREAM on NTFS compressed folder is possible and a valid option, as long as you're willing to go with FILESTREAM.

Comment: you need developer/enterprise edition for row/page compression

Answer (score 3):

In additional to row/page comperssion you can use FILESTREAMS to store field on compressed NTFS drive.  But your files is not so big and comression will be a best choise.

Comment: With the FILESTREAMS option, would the text data be queryable?

Comment: oh ok - that sounds like it would be really useful.  So the data is actually stored out on the disk?  Can you point me at a how-to guide for setting this up?  If it retains queryability but actually stores data on disk, this might be what I need

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/