# Compressing an XML column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

Is there a straight-forward way to compress an XML data-typed column in SQL Server 2008 R2 standard edition?

My constraints are:

1. SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition;
2. Must store raw XMl in the database;

I have previously asked a similar question about generalized text storage [Compressing a text field in Sql Server 2k8 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546138/compressing-a-text-field-in-sql-server-2k8-r2) the result of which was to use FILESTREAMS.  If I do that here though I'll lose all the XML functionality SQL Server exposes, which I'd like to leverage.

Comment: You can't compress specific columns - but in SQL Server 2008 and newer, you can compress either rows or pages - see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2007/11/12/types-of-data-compression-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) for an introduction

Answer (score 4):

You can always store the XML as NVARCHAR and then utilize XML functionality on a view against that column that converts the data to XML first. However you would have to weigh how much that run-time work offsets the benefits of the compression (there will be significant CPU overhead, proportional to the amount of compression you actually achieve). I can understand the desire to do this kind of thing in an I/O-bound system, but I suspect that XML columns are not candidates for compression for precisely this reason - the costs are going to outweigh the benefits more often than not. If you're really intent on storing the data as compressed, and your biggest concern is storage space, I would consider letting your application do the compression (C# is much more flexible here than T-SQL and native compression will be, I expect) and also let your application deal with the XML features.

Answer (score 0):

[PAGE/ROW COMPRESSION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx), the only ‘straightforward’ way I'm aware of, does not work for XML columns because it does not work for LOB pages.
There is a work-around using CLR-implemented GZIP compression, as explained
[in this very good article](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2015/04/07/compressing-lob-xml-data-in-the-database/). One drawback is that the whole XML must fit into memory when executing queries. Furthermore it can be
considerably slow, so *“you should be careful and take all … factors into the consideration”*.